# Error: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI - Using Object type for passing value

Tags: javascript, routes

I cannot seem to get my JavaScript HTTP call to route to my controller using the following address. I am trying to pass an int, object, bool, bool from JavaScript. Any idea why I am getting the error?

**JavaScript Service Call**

```
    ClassManager.httpPost("/folder/TestCall/" + $sessionStorage.testId, TestObject, isTest, isValid)
```

**Route to Controller**

```
    [Route("api/TestCall/{testId:int}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TestCall(int testId, TestObject testInfo, bool isTest, bool isValid)
```

**Error**

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:1234/folder/TestCall/44444'.

44444 = testId value

Answer (score 0):

your javascript service call should be: `"/api/TestCall/"` not `"/folder/TestCall/"`

```
ClassManager.httpPost("/api/TestCall/" + $sessionStorage.testId, TestObject, isTest, isValid)
```